# Alternatives to Adobe's PDF Optimizer?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Acrobat Professional features a PDF Optimizer tool, as reviewed [here](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/pdf/optimizer.html).

This tool analyzes the space usage within a PDF file in terms of image size, fonts, ...

Are there more lightweight and/or affordable tools that do the same for existing PDF files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such tools.

You can try to get the information you want with [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) and build such a tool yourself.

Here is a howto to [reduce the PDF file size from the command line](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphowto-reduce-adobe-acrobat-file-size-from-command-line.html).

Comment: Neither Ghostscript nor PDFTK are able to analayze *space usage* for different categories of page objects and resources. An answer like the above would be completely useless *even if Ghostscript or PDFTK* ***could indeed*** *do what's required* ...unless it also gave a detailed commandline which would achieve what Bernard asked for.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be any tools for this around, they could be used as stepping stones to build such a tool.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to make it more obvious that one link goes to a HOWTO which might help.